# как получать значения в Jquery для простых расчётов?

Tags: jquery

Учусь основам программирования. Пытаюсь сделать элементарные программки для рассчёта площадей, попутно дорабатывая. Но никак не могу получить значения из input. Где я не прав, что следует почитать, что подправить?)

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Экспериментальная станица</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Рассчёт площади квадрата</h1>
<input type="number" id="first" placeholder="введите число"> Введите длину </br>
<input type="number" id="second" placeholder="введите число"> Введите высоту </br>
<button id="shet">Рассчитать площадь</button> </br>

<h3 id="vivod"></h3>

</body>
</html>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function(){
    $("shet").on("click", function(){
        var dlina = $("#first]").val();
        var visota = $("#second").val();
        var itog = dlina*visota;
        var vivod = $("<h3></h3>").html(itog);
        $("#vivod").append(vivod);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помимо остальных ошибок... внутри элементов h1...h6 не может быть какой-либо еще другой тег. Браузер видит, что начался тег h, смотрит дальше - как только начался новый тег, но h еще не закрыт, автоматически закрывает его, потом идет дальше.

```js
$(function(){
    $("#shet").on("click", function(){ // Здесь было "shet" - забыта клетка
        var dlina = $("#first").val(); // #first] - лишняя квадратная скобка
        var visota = $("#second").val();
        var itog = dlina*visota;
        $("#vivod").html(itog); // И так есть пустой h3 с этим id, в него и можно 
        //поставить ответ, а не создавать каждый раз новый элемент
    });
});
// Переменные кстати не обязательно всегда создавать... 
// Если легко получается разбираться в написанном, можно и одной строчкой:
// $("#vivod").html( $("#first").val() * $("#second").val() );

// Если больше нигде не будут использованы эти числа...
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Рассчёт площади квадрата</h1>
<input type="number" id="first" placeholder="введите число"> Введите длину <br>
<input type="number" id="second" placeholder="введите число"> Введите высоту <br>
<button id="shet">Рассчитать площадь</button> 

<h3 id="vivod"></h3>
```

Но в подобных простых случаях, можно использовать моментальный подсчет, без кнопки подтверждения. Пользователю придется сделать 1-м кликом меньше... мелочь, а приятно))

```js
$(function(){
    $("#first, #second").on("input", function(){
        var dlina = $("#first").val();
        var visota = $("#second").val();
        var itog = dlina*visota;
        $("#vivod").html(itog);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Рассчёт площади квадрата</h1>
<input type="number" id="first" placeholder="введите число"> Введите длину <br>
<input type="number" id="second" placeholder="введите число"> Введите высоту <br>

<h3 id="vivod"></h3>
```

(Мне было скучно)

Есть еще такой фокус, событие `keyup` срабатывает почти как `input`, только при нажатии вообще любой кнопки, а не только во время печати. И у него есть фишка, определяющая нажатую кнопку... `e.key` ниже добавлено переключение фокуса с инпута, при нажатии `Enter`

```js
$(function(){
//Ту же функцию, объявили с названием count, чтобы ниже дважды не повторять запись.
function count(){
  var dlina = $("#first").val();
  var visota = $("#second").val();
  var itog = dlina*visota;
  $("#vivod").html(itog);
};
    
$('#first').on('keyup', function(e){
  count(); // Вызвали функцию-считалку
  // Символ == используется для сравнения двух значений.
  if( e.key == 'Enter' ) { //При нажатии enter - переключаем фокус на другой инпут
    $('#second').focus();
  }
});
$('#second').on('keyup', function(e){
  count(); // Также вызываем считалку
  if( e.key == 'Enter' ) {
    $('#first').focus();
  }
});
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Рассчёт площади квадрата</h1>
<input type="number" id="first" placeholder="введите число"> Введите длину <br>
<input type="number" id="second" placeholder="введите число"> Введите высоту <br>

<h3 id="vivod"></h3>
```

P.s. пишите код в каком-нибудь редакторе, чтобы избежать хотя бы ошибок по невнимательности:

https://liveweave.com/ , https://playcode.io , https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Большое спасибо за разъяснение, особенно комменты к каждой строке)) Ошибки возникли из-за попытки переделать код, читал в инете, но никак не мог понять что не так)) В итоге подумал что стоит переделать как показано в примере взятого из инета. Оттуда и косяки с квадратными скобками и попытка записать новый <h3>. А по сути оказалось что я в shet просто пропустил #. И из-за этого так долго мудил) А оказывается всё нормально по сути. Ато я только сегодня дочитал в Sololearn про Jquery, сразу решил немного попрактиковаться. Значит не так безнадёжен... наверное)) Первый день немного комом) СПАСИБО !

Comment: Думаю надо голове дать немного передохнуть и завтра обязательно прочитаю и разберу материал про доработку кода) Думаю есть что для себя взять) Ещё раз благодарю =)